# can i add my own css class in seperate css file in bootstrap and still my website will be responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am working on helpdesk system and i am creating this system in **mvc**.

i am designing this system in **bootstrap framework**.i have created my **master page with bootstrap template.**

i am using **bootstrap.min.css file for bootstrap design.**

so my question is can i use my own **css** for my **render body** design and can i create my own css file and add those css class and so my website will be responsive ???

or should i have to write those **css in bootstrap.min.css file**.

but when i am adding my own **css class in bootstrap.min.css then there is no effect of css**.

can u guys me some suggestions please????????

Answer (score 3):

you should write your own css and add link. don't change bootstrap.min.css. 
and your site will be responsive

Comment: so i can design my render body with my own css file??

Comment: yes, sure . you can use it. make sure that you don't use % in your own css when you used responsive class for a tag. use px

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap.min.css is only for the default styling of spans and rows using Bootstrap. You can and should write your own css file to override any of the basic styling, instead of modifying Bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: so i can design my render body with my own css file and what if i give width to my render body div tag??

Comment: Yeah you can do that too. It is possible to override all bootstrap css.

Comment: no i am not asking to override bootstrap css.i am asking that if my render body is set with some width like say 500px r somethng and if i am opening dat on mobile r tablet then dat responsive feature will be lost naa?

Comment: @priyankavashi  With a custom css file, you'll potentially be overriding the bootstrap css, if you use selectors wisely. Try it out and see what css rules are overridden with a web inspector. 

Also, please use as much correct English as possible on Stack Overflow - words like 'dat', 'naa' and 'r' make it troublesome to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Well yeah if you explicitly set the width then the width will not change. If you use the bootstrap framework, instead of width you can declare span12 or span6 something like that and it will resize depending on your screen width. Otherwise if you need to set the width explicitly, you can use css @media queries to set the width at different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use your own css independently of the css of the framework "bootstrap", of course.

Write the properties in the bootstrap.min.css is not well. It's more clean to write your property in a new css file or directly in the html tag of which you want add your property with the 'style' attribute.

Example :

```
  <a style="text-decoration:none;color:red;">
```

Now, if you use your own property css, it can happen that some properties is applied to your component by default because you use bootstrap. To use your property value and not coming from 'bootstrap', you have to use "!important".

Example :

```
color : black !important;
```

Comment: bt if i am designing my render body which contain some width then will be website will be responsive??

Answer (score 0):

Do not edit the bootstrap.min.css file. Use that as your base and then include your own CSS roles after it so that any changes you make will overwrite the bootstrap.min.css file leaving you with the code that you customized.